# Why is the new user reputation not displayed in bold?

Tags: bug, users, design

I noticed that the reputation on this page https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=newusers is not bold, but it is on all the other tabs under Users.

Is there a reason or is it a bug?

Comment: Looking at the link provided, I'm not seeing reputation listed a all.

Comment: @Xarcell The text next to the user icon states how much reputation a new users has earned in the past X days. Which is most likely also part of the "problem". It's not a pure reputation listing, but part of a larger string.

Comment: Gotcha, I see what your saying now.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call this a BUG. This is more of a design issue for StackOverflow Meta. Simply adjusting your HTML or CSS for it will make it more visible, which I don't even really think is necessary, or be considered a top priority, but I do see how you can view it as an issue.

**EDIT**: Since it is not consistent, it should be adjusted to reflect it's siblings.

Comment: It's not a big thing but I see the reputation in bold on the other pages. So I am wondering why it's not consistent.

Comment: If it's not consistent, then yes it should be bold. A design flaw.

Comment: The meta tag used for such issues is always [bug], so...

Comment: @BoltClock As a designer myself, I disagree. The "Design" tag should be used, which he as used anyway along with the "Bug" tag.

Comment: I know that. My point is that the required tag for reporting technical issues, regardless of their nature, is [bug] - you can always use the [design] tag to indicate that it's a design issue, but you still have to use [bug] because none of the other required tags fit the purpose.